# ggplot2/qplot ignores bins valued 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

So, I have something like this in R

```
f = factor(c(0,1,0,1,0), levels = c(0,1,2))
```

which, if plotted like

```
plot(f)
```

produces a nice chart showing that I have three 0, two 1, and zero 2. Nice. Until I use qplot, that is

```
qplot(f)
```

produces a supernice chart showing that I have three 0, and two 1. Not nice. I do need to retain that information about the third level. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
qplot(f) + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[Arguments:drop](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/discrete_scale.html)